# Welford's algorithm for standard deviation: combine multiple sets of results

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Suppose I use [Welford's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) to compute the standard deviation of multiple sets of values. I only store all the n, mean and M2 results that the algorithm calculates, thus I have these three results per set.

Is it possible to calculate the standard deviation over all samples in all sets, by using only the stored results? Thus I'm looking for a way to combine the n, mean and M2 results. For n and mean this is trivial, but I don't know how to combine the M2 values.

Note: this would be easy when I would use the [naive sum of squares algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Na.C3.AFve_algorithm), but wikipedia recommends against using this algorithm in practice.

Note2: I cannot store all values in all sets, I'm writing software that only gets one chance to do something with each value, thus the algorithm needs to be 'incremental' or 'online'.

Comment: If you have the standard deviation for each set, you could compute the pooled standard deviation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance